# How do I use the Syncano Javascript user API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syncano

I can't figure out how to use the Syncano Javascript user API in a node.js web app to log in a user, nor to create a new user, nor to fetch the user given the user auth token.

Is there sample code showing this anywhere, or more comprehensive docs? Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.syncano.io/docs/javascript

Comment: That's not nearly comprehensive enough. It merely shows you how to install it and get the top-level object. Absolutely nothing about how to use the other classes.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Looks like 1.0.2 (whatever is most recent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform `npm run build`, there will be a new sub-folder called `docs`.  Open up index.html and you will have a full lib overview.

Also, the [HTTP API Reference](http://docs.syncano.io/v0.1.1/docs/) will have a `JavaScript` tag for most code examples. You will want to find the sections for `Users` and `User`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. The link to the HTTP API Reference did the trick. This should get me a lot farther along. I didn't have to even build the project (I tried, but it failed. I assume I need to clone the repo and execute the npm run build command in that?). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you would need to clone it, install dependencies and run the build script.